Proving that the random variable $\frac{\mathrm{e}^{t Z}-1}{t Z}$ satisfies Kolmogorov's theorem on conditional expectations
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two i.i.d. $\operatorname{Exp}(1)$ random variables, and $Z=X+Y$.
(a) Write down an actual probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ to model this situation.
(b) Fix any $t \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0<|t|<1$ and show that the random variable $\frac{\mathrm{e}^{t Z}-1}{t Z}$ satisfies Kolmogorov's theorem on conditional expectations for $\mathbb{E}\left(\mathrm{e}^{t X} \mid Z\right)$, hence by uniqueness $\frac{\mathrm{e}^{t Z}-1}{t Z}$ is a version of this conditional expectation.
Would anyone be able to give me some advice on how to approach this question. For (a) I'm fairly certain the answer should be:
$$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})=([0, \infty) \times[0, \infty), \mathcal{B}([0, \infty) \times[0, \infty)), \mathbb{P})$$
although I'm not sure if I've formatted it properly.
However for (b) I'm struggling to justify the first requirement of Kolmogorov's theorem which is that if $Z$ is $\mathcal{G}-measurable$ then $\frac{\mathrm{e}^{t Z}-1}{t Z}$ is also $\mathcal{G}-measurable$. I'm trying to use the fact that a continuous function on a measurable function is measurable as well, however $\frac{\mathrm{e}^{t Z}-1}{t Z}$ is undefined on 0. Here is my solution but I'm uncertain if I've overcomplicated the answer:
Using a theorem from Measure Theory, a continuous function on the codomain of a measurable function is measurable. The function
$$
V=\frac{e^{(t Z)}-1}{t Z}
$$
is the quotient of 2 continuous functions but is undefined at 0 . But if we extend the function
\begin{equation}
f(Z)= \begin{cases}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{t Z}-1}{t Z}, & Z \neq 0\\ \newline 1, & Z=0\end{cases}
\end{equation}
to define it to equal 1 when $Z=0$ which matches its limit at 0 (by L'Hôpital's rule) then the function is measurable.
